# Is it a best practice to create a jQuery plug-in that is stateful ? If so, how do I do that?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Let's suppose we have a jQuery pager plug-in. So I would be able to do this:

```
$("pager-div").pager({ page: 1, rowsPerPage: 30, count: 1780 });
```

Ok. Now I want to move the pager to the next page. I have two options here:

1) My plug-in `$.pager` does not return jQuery. It returns an object that has a method called `nextPage` so I could do something like this:

```
var pager = $("pager-div").pager({ page: 1, rowsPerPage: 30, count: 1780 });
pager.nextPage();
```

2) My plug-in returns jQuery. It's better so it maintains chainability. So I could do something like this:

```
$("pager-div").pager({ page: 1, rowsPerPage: 30, count: 1780 });
$("pager-div").nextPage();
```

Two questions here:

1. It seems to me that approach 2 is better as it maintains chainabilty and I would'nt have the need to keep reference to the pager. I could access it anywhere using the $ function. The question is: Should I use approach 2?
2. If the answer of (1) is true, how do I implement it? That is, how to I maintain state in the jQuery?

Comment: you wouldn't maintain state in jQuery itself, per se, you could use browser technology to store the info: cookies, localStorage, etc.

Comment: you can store your state vars in the jQuery object's data() object. If that's what you meant?

Answer (score 3):

I vote for option 2. You can store your variables controlled in the data field of jQuery.

example:

```
$(selector).data("option", {page: 1});
alert($.data("option").page);
```